# ASP.NET Core/Blazor - The {PropertyName} field must be a number - how to change the property name on error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, data-annotations

Good Day Everyone

I have a Model that has integer property like this.

```
[Display(Name = "Price")]
[Range(1,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage ="This field is required.")]
public int ItemPrice { get; set;}
```

Now when validating the fields on my page, let's say I put a 1.5 or let's say a blank, then submit the page. Now the error shows the property name like this:

**"The ItemPrice field must be a number"**

It does not show like **"The Price field must be a number"**

I'm trying to change it but it does not work, how can I change name on the error message by using the display name instead of the property name?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I think it is important you tell use which validator you are using first.

Comment: Apologies, but how do you expect the validator to be a magician?  Where does it get the error message "The Price field must be a number". The field name is `ItemPrice` and 1.5 is not an integer!

Comment: What if you change the data type to `decimal` in `int 1.5` shouldn't consider as valid input.